# Error while running Cordova build android ionic2

Tags: cordova, ionic2, css-position

I'm trying to build android in cordova ionic 2 but an error occurred 
JAVA_HOME is invalid C:\program file\java\jdk\jre
can someone help

Comment: Could you please post the output of your build log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add JAVA_HOME as below.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to java environment variables path

1. Right click My Computer and select Properties.
2. On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit
   JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for
   example, C:\program file\java\jdk\jre.
   **Make sure this jdk actually in this path**

after this run `android` in the cmd , if it is set correctly the android SDK Manager will open.

Check [Set the Jdk path](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/)